# How to mix Node.js and Typescript in the same Visual Studio project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, typescript, ntvs

Visual Studio has a **Typescript** addon for developing apps with the Typescript language.

And there is also the **Node.js** Tools for VS, with which one is able to create and debug Node.js applications.

I tried creating a Node.js project, but then I couldn't add Typescript files to it, and if I added them by hand, they did not get compiled to javascript (couldn't set their Build action to TypeScriptCompile.)
And if I create a simple Typescript project, then it does not start my app with Node, because it is basically just an ASP.Net web project.

Is it possible to somehow create a VS project that uses Typescript and Node.js integration at the same time?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, but in a somewhat awkward way (I hope Node.js Tools will support this better in the future).

You should create Node.js project and add a new file. Choose new text file and enter its name with .ts extension. It will create a typescript file.

At this point you will have a typescript files without compiled javascript.

To fix this go to  VS "Tools" menu, open "Options" and go to "Text editor" > "TypeScript" > "Project" and under "Compile on Save" check "Automatically compile TypeScript files which are not part of a project and choose "Use commonjs...".

After that open each .ts file and save it - tsc will compile it to javascript.

Downside of this solution is that you have to remember to save manually each .ts you edit, but I think its not a big deal.

Here's a link to the post that helped me with the same problem: http://blog.ctaggart.com/2013/11/nodejs-tools-with-typescript-console-app.html

**Update**

If you grab the latest dev build of Node.js Tools you will see that TypeScript support is added. you can create TypeScript project (and this includes debugging .ts files feature)

https://nodejstools.codeplex.com/discussions/531222